# WifiAwareManager returns null

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-wifi

I'm trying to create an application that uses Wifi Aware but my WifiAwareManager returns null. How can I properly initialize the class so that it does not return null? What is the cause of this behavior? I'm quite sure that Pixel 2 XL does support Wifi Aware, am I wrong?

```
final WifiAwareManager wifiAwareManager = (WifiAwareManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_AWARE_SERVICE);

if (wifiAwareManager.isAvailable()) {
    System.out.println("aware avaiable");
} else {
    System.out.println("aware not avaiable");
}
```

The logcat is:

```
2018-10-11 12:45:53.926 4003-4003/com.example.lucapalmieri.awarecheckE/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.lucapalmieri.awarecheck, PID: 4003
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:389)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:384)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) 
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.net.wifi.aware.WifiAwareManager.isAvailable()' on a null object reference
    at com.example.lucapalmieri.awarecheck.MainActivity.check(MainActivity.java:71)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:384) 
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: You have added the `nullpointerexception` tag to your question. If you are getting this error then please post the error stack from the logcat.

Comment: Updated, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Cause isAvailiable is added only from api level 26 as WifiAwareManager. I assume you are using android with version lower than Android 8.0
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/aware/WifiAwareManager.html#isAvailable()